# Can someone help solve recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

It says to solve the recurrence exactly for `n` a power of 2.

```
T(n) = {1}, if n = 1

T(n) = {5T(n/2) + (n lg n)^2, otherwise
```

I'm supposed to use `Θ` notation to express my answer.

Normally I would try to look for the characteristic equation but for this one I'm lost.

Is this the first step?

```
T(n) - 5T(n/2) = (n lg n )^2
```

This is not a duplicate as it has not been posted there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I fail to see where my question was asked on that post.

Comment: If you skip down to the answer that talks about the Master Theorem, you'll find that it is appropriate for your problem.